# Android: How do I set TextView for each item in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I need someone to point me in the right direction on this....

In my Android application I have a ListView with custom views for each row containing various textviews each. I retrieve weather information for multiple locations and then want to write the results for each location to its own listview item. The question is, how do I refer to each textview on each listview item?

I can't do it by name using `findViewById`, can I? If there are three items in the list, will the temperature textview for each item be names the same, just differ by an array index? If so, how do I specify TextViewName(0), TextViewName(1) and TextViewName (2) for the three list items?

Yes, I'm still very new to Android....but loving it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this when each item is created (or recycled) in the getView method that you should override in the adapter.
Watch the google io talk from 2011 on list views and it should be quite clear how they work.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Great video. Thanks for the link, it answered my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a type of adapter: 
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516